# Content Security Policy: Is data: applied to all items in the img-src source list?

Tags: content-security-policy

I've got a content security policy and I'm trying to determine if I can allow data images, such as base 64 encoded PNG's (CSS code), to just 'self' or if it must apply to all sources in the list. I can't find any documentation that tells me what data: is applied to. I assume then it's applied to the entire source list. Can anyone confirm?

```
img-src 'self' https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://ajax.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.googletagmanager.com data:;
```

I'm also trying to determine if there is any security concerns with this img-src. Thank you for any comments.

Answer (score 1):

`'self'` and `data:` are both [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#values). Neither apply to each other. Both apply to [directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#directives) (in this case `img-src`).

Comment: data: is a scheme. So, I guess it depends on the allowed CSS files, in this case. Any allowed CSS files could use a data: source to load just about anything. That seems a bit insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Images are typically not a security threat by themselves, particularly when they are loaded as data: in an allowlisted CSS file. It could be a way to smuggle a script, but images don't carry the same risk.

Images could potentially carry malicious content, but the main reason to restrict img-src would be to prevent data exfiltration in image URLs. This would not apply to the data scheme.